# WordPress add_image_size() creates additional images not defined

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the functions.php file of my wordpress theme (FoodRecipes), I find the following code.

```
if( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
        add_image_size( 'thumbnail-blog', 575, 262, true); // for blog pages
        add_image_size( 'recipe-listing', 250, 212, true); // For recipe listing page
        add_image_size( 'portfolio-thumb', 220, 140, true); // for the portfolio template
        add_image_size( 'portfolio-main', 940, '', false); // for the single portfolio page
        add_image_size( 'full-size', '', '', false);
        add_image_size( 'sidebar-tabs', 63, 53, true);
        add_image_size( 'recipe-4column-thumb', 222, 144, true);
        add_image_size( 'single-carousel-thumb', 132, 104, true);
        add_image_size( 'li-slider-thumb', 515, 262, true);
        add_image_size( 'bs-slider-thumb', 903, 386, true);
        add_image_size( 'weekly-special-thumb', 122, 132, true);
        add_image_size( 'most-rated-thumb', 63, 53, true);
}
```

When I up upload a 932x603 image and view what size images were created, I find that most of those sizes were created (but not all), and some extra were created which I can't account for. Here are the exceptions...

1) The 940x'' image was NOT created. I'm guessing that's because the original image was smaller than 940. Right?

2) A 150x150 image was created. Why?

3) A 300x194 image was created. Why?

For the extra images that were created, I can't figure out where the direction to create those specific sizes comes from. Where should I be looking? Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: The 150x150 and 300x194 correspond to WordPress' `Thumbnail` and `Medium` sizes, as seen in the Admin -> Settings -> Media. I'm not sure whey you're not seeing the `Large` size though (1024x1024).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Settings > Media, you'll find that there are three media sizes defined by default:

1. 150x150 cropped ("thumbnail", also known as "post-thumbnail" or "thumb")
2. 300x300 ("medium")
3. 1024x1024 ("large")

... and of course there is also "full" for the original image.

When you upload an image, WordPress will create versions of that image at all defined sizes up to - but not larger than - the image you uploaded.

So your 932x603 image will create a 150x150 thumbnail (cropped to exactly 150x150), as well as a 300x194 medium image (proportional). It will not crate a 1024x662 or any other image size larger than your original - which is why there was no 940px wide image created either.

Comment: Thanks, the info about an image not being made if the source image is smaller makes total sense, but didn't think to check that.